# How to rename custom table name programatically in wordpress?

Tags: database

in db there are custom table name like wp_wpdf_docs and want to change table name to wp_ccdm_docs

as i am using

```
    $oldtable_name = $wpdb->prefix . "wpfd_docs"; 

    $newtable_name = $wpdb->prefix . "ccdm_docs"; 

    $rename=  $wpdb->query("RENAME TABLE ".$oldtable_name ." TO " .$newtable_name);
```

is it right process?

Comment: Can't you test it locally to see if it works? The big question will be: Where is that table used? If the old name is referenced after the rename, that will run you into trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `query` function to rename tables.

```
global $wpdb;
$oldTable = $wpdb->prefix . "wpfd_docs";
$newTable = $wpdb->prefix . "ccdm_docs"; 
$renameOk = $wpdb->query("RENAME TABLE " . $oldTable . " TO " . $newTable);
if( $renameOk )
{
    echo 'All good';
}else{
    echo 'Failed to rename table. Last DB error: ' . $wpdb->last_error;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @hbit The code works perfectly ...